# Divisibility of $2^x-1 $

Tags: elementary-number-theory

This is one of the first questions on round 1 of the Korean Math Olympiad

Find all natural numbers x, y such that $xy=2^x-1$

I "know" that the only solution is  $(x,y)=(1,1)$, but I cannot find a proof of this

Comment: So $0 \notin \mathbb N$? Because $(0,y)$ with $y \in \mathbb N$ would be also possible

Comment: @KarthikT  i have tried to answer this question by different way,please see it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lemma. If $a\not\equiv1,a^n\equiv1$ mod $m$ then $(n,\varphi(m))>1$.

Let $p\mid x$ be the smallest prime divisor. Now $p>2$, and $2^x\equiv1$ mod $p$ implies $(x,p-1)>1$ ...

Comment: i have tried using arithmetic comparison

Comment: i have deleted my answer,good lucks

Comment: thank you for downvoting,but i have deleted already :D

Comment: This is brilliant! Thanks a lot for this, I knew I had to look for a contradiction, but had no clue as to where to start!